# reCaptcha Error: Please complete the captcha

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to setup this site but this bug is annoying me, how do I fix this  complete the captcha error i keep getting?

Running on Laravel

I don't know why it keeps showing in this information but it should be leading me to the next page. If you need more information to this, use the other site, bustablox.com which works but I need help with bustablox.net

```
<!-- ReCaptcha -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
```

````
<div class="tab-content">
                    <div id="signupslide">   
                        <form class="register">
                            <div class="field-wrap">
                                <input type="text" class="" id="username" placeholder="Username">
                            </div>
                            <div class="field-wrap">
                                <input type="email" class="" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="field-wrap">
                                <input type="password" class="" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                            <br><br><br><br>
                            <button type="button" id="register" class="login-button btn btn-success">Register</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                    <div id="loginslide">                  
                        <form class="login">
                            <div class="field-wrap">
                                <input type="text" class="" id="username" placeholder="Username">
                            </div>
                            <div class="field-wrap">
                                <input type="password" class="" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                            <br><br><br><br>
                            <button type="button" id="login" class="login-button btn btn-success">Login</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>```
````

````
        $("body").on("click", "#register", function() {
            var $username = $(".register #username").val();
            var $email = $(".register #email").val();
            var $password = $(".register #password").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/account?username=' + $username + "&password=" + $password + "&email=" + $email + "&type=register&captcha=" + grecaptcha.getResponse(),
                method: "GET",
                success: function(data) {
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                    if(data.success) {
                        $("#alerta").html(`
                            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">` + data.msg + `</div>
                        `);
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            document.location.href = '/';
                        }, 1500);
                    } else {
                        $("#alerta").html(`
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">` + data.msg + `</div>
                        `);
                        grecaptcha.reset();
                    }
                }
            })
        });

        $("body").on("click", "#login", function() {
            var $username = $(".login #username").val();
            var $password = $(".login #password").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/account?username=' + $username + "&password=" + $password + "&type=login&captcha=" + grecaptcha.getResponse(),
                method: "GET",
                success: function(data) {
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                    if(data.success) {
                        $("#alerta").html(`
                            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">` + data.msg + `</div>
                        `);
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            document.location.href = '/';
                        }, 1500);
                    } else {
                        $("#alerta").html(`
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">` + data.msg + `</div>
                        `);
                        grecaptcha.reset();
                    }
                }
            })
        });

    });```

Should be leading me to the next page but this error message keeps coming "Please complete the captcha!"
````

Comment: Why not using the [official example](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display)?  it is easier than this

Comment: I wished my developer didn't make it like this